# Android: How to intercept keydown globally (on hardware keyboard)

Tags: android, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, mobile-application

Is there a possibility for an android app to run as a service in the background, intercept keydown events from the **hardware** keyboard and change behavior (i.e. the resulting character) in some special cases?

The idea in mind is to have sort of a keyboard layout fix, mainly making important special characters available using an alternative keymap instead of having to select from a huge grid on the touch screen. Sometimes, the default keymap of a mobile devices do not represent all important characters, even more when it comes to non-english languages.

Thanks for inspiration :)
Peter

EDIT: additionally emphasized **hardware**

Comment: Wouldn't this be the mother of all security holes?

Comment: If abused, yes. As many other things apps can do. I guess the fact that it can be abused does not mean that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is in fact not  a service in background but replacing the keyboard app itself..take a look at the SWype app.

You do not have to create a service to do this as you want just the your own keyboard layout coming up when entering text, etc.

The sample of replacing a default app in the sdk is the homescreen but the keyboard app can be replaced as well..

Comment: Actually, (fortunately) my keyboard is not an app, but a piece of hardware to slide out :) Of course, I could be using a software keyboard but... no ;-)

Comment: that is the way you would do it not by attempting to have a runonboot service as the other way opens security holes.

Comment: Hm, so you are saying that the hardware keyboard is managed by a piece of software which is an app itself? That's interesting... Maybe I'll have to do quite some more research on this, but with my current (decent) knowledge I cannot imagine how this replacement could be achieved. And how this app would look like. I could not really find any information on this, so if you know a good link, I would be happy to hear from you :) Thanks a lot for your input